# Use 4G while being connected to a WiFi direct printer

Tags: wi-fi, networking, wifi-direct

Is it possible to use 4G for internet while being connected to a wireless printer with WiFi direct?

If not, are there any alternatives to use both, the printer as well as the internet, simultaneously without requiring another WiFi access point?

(The printer in question is the Epson L3150 Wireless Printer)

Comment: Does your device has the option "Cellular data always active" (Settings -> Developer Options)? Note that the developer options have to be enabled first.

Comment: If Epson or the device manufacturer has a printer plugin in Google Play store for wifi then you don't have to use wifi direct.

Answer (score 1):

This is an ongoing issue that has been described as an optional implementation of the wifi direct. Or rather a lack of implemented options. My self a team testing an app for a developer, found that some phones have an option or feature for load balancing over wifi and data as a feature. Those that have this balancing, print and access internet without issue. Those without have no data over cellular while connected to wifi.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking to the similar solution with my 360 camera and I found it. Even though my problem seems to be more complicated than yours. I needed some app to get data from internet while my phone wifi was being used for wireless connection with the camera. The app just always wanted to use wifi to get data and ignored all settings and even restrictions through mobiwal to use mobile connection only.

Below is where I asked about it and described a solution before I got any answers

[Need wifi to be connected to a camera(no internet) and one app using 4G for internet](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/214095/need-wifi-to-be-connected-to-a-camerano-internet-and-one-app-using-4g-for-inte)

In your case, why don't you want to try to do it as simple as that:

1)create a hotspot on your phone where your 4G connection 
2) connect your printer to the hotspot?

I did almost the same but in my case I used a second phone just as a hotspot. The reason I had to do it that way is I cannot connect to anything from the camera directly so I had to go through Wireless LAN client mode as a feature of the camera. In your case your printer should have some kind of screen that can help to connect to your hotspot.